# Expose ingress path inside cluster but not on public?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a pod that has following chart:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    // ...
  paths:
    - /api/myservice
```

My pod exposes api and additionally a `/prometheus` endpoint that is accessible through `/api/myservice/prometheus`.

I would like to have `prometheus` visible inside my cluster but not from `/api/myservice/prometheus`. How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

You can add an Ingress rule that redirects the endpoint to the default-backend:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: block
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myapp.to
  rules:
  - host: myapp.to
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /metrics
        backend:
          serviceName: ingress-default-backend
          servicePort: 8080
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need internal access, I don't think you should put it into ingress. You could make use of the [DNS Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) together with Kubernetes cluster already.

If your prometheus service is running the same namespace as your working pod, you could use following address to access it.

```
http://prometheus-svc-name
```

If your prometheus service is running in a different namespace, you could use:

```
http://prometheus-svc-name.prometheus-namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

to access the service.

**Update:**

More clear about the question after comments.

You could write another rule to hide your `/prometheus` endpoint like this:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    // ...
  paths:
    - /api/myservice => myservice
    - /api/myservice/prometheus => 404 default backend.
```

nginx-ingress will match the longest route first. It will route `/api/myservice/prometheus` to 404. [See this documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/ingress-path-matching.md)

Comment: In my pod I need external API and at the same time one endpoint that will be scraped internally by prometheus ( which is accessible trough `/prometheus`)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Will update my answer. You would need another ingress to achieve this.

Comment: Please refer to Amityo's answer. You would need to run a default-backend service though. Check this yaml config for example: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/e8d81034b8f6b3308caac85280e4cf3d93baee1c/deploy/default-backend.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve this would be to remove the prometheus endpoint from ingress and if you are aware prometheus supports auto discovery using annotations on the service, configure prometheus for k8s auto discovery and then add annotations in you service yaml file.
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config

Comment: Ok but how I'm supposed to remove prometheus endpoint from ingress? It lies underneath `/api/myservice` so from outside world it's accessible trough `/api/myservice/prometheus`.

Answer (score 0):

change the endpoint to point to your API.
/api/myservice/my-api or use app-root annotation, to point to your api inside /api/myservice:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /path/to/my/app/root/dir
```

more details here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite

Comment: and then how I would be able to access `/prometheus` endpoint within my cluster?

Comment: if you don't want to use ingress for /Prometheus anyways, you can use port forward to access the /Prometheus within cluster provided the services is exposed using clusterIP (default behavior).

The service can also be exposed using node-port, to be available from any <node IP>:<node port> But it makes almost no sense using both.

Options:
1.Using a single ingress can solve your problem for both but both will be exposed just do not use app-root.

2.Use separate ingress for both and use authentication for Prometheus in ingress. That ways you will still have control over who can access it.