# How do I block paths in my (k8s) ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a subset of paths that I expose with an ingress.
I'd like to block them for anyone coming through the ingress.

I'm trying this with a GCE Ingress

Adding a rule like:

```
 - host: my.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: dead-end-backend
          servicePort: 80
        path: /private
```

This backend is designated dead-end using Nginx default backend deployment/service but it's not working well.

I'm not asking how to use the default-backend (but it solve it).

I'm asking for a **proper** way to do this.

Comment: Can you show some examples of what you want to achieve? k8s version, ingress controller name, current ingress YAML will be a plus.

Comment: added details about ingress, it's a GKE.

Comment: Why do you want to expose your path and block it? What´s the purpose? If you´re bound to gke ingress then I don´t think there is better way than that you´re actually doing, if you could use other like nginx-ingress then you should be able to do that with server-snippet, for example take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57411698/how-to-set-ingress-nginx-custom-errors/57413732#57413732).

Comment: For example, all of my deployments expose /metrics and i don't want it to be publicly available

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes Ingress network deny some paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874503/kubernetes-ingress-network-deny-some-paths)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expose ingress path inside cluster but not on public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55209826/expose-ingress-path-inside-cluster-but-not-on-public)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the best thing to do but what I did was use a "default-backend" service which returns error for anything.
Then I added each route I wanted to block to get to that default backend.

Like the saying - if it's silly, but it's working, then it's not silly.

Comment: just make sure you leave a healthcheck in there that still returns 200